# UITableView Swipe Cell's Border

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm using Swift 5 and Xcode 11.4.1 on macOS Catalina.

[image: Swipe-able UITableView Cell Image]

I used this method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? { //code }
```

to make the cell swipe-able.

And then, I made the border rounded with this code below.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = arr[indexPath.section]
    
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell
}
```

After I un-swipe particular cell (In this image below, I did with the second cell), the rounded corner is changed as square border.

[image: After the cell no.2 swiped image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace these lines of code:

```
 cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
 cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
 cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
 cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Thank you sir. You save my life! XD